# Unable to run shell script from the Pydev environment in Eclipse

Tags: python, linux, eclipse, shell, subprocess

I am using Centos 7.0 and have installed Eclipse Kepler in the Pydev environment. I want to run a simple c shell script through Python using subprocess as follows:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["./test1.csh"])
```

This c shell script executes in the terminal and also if I run command like "ls" or ""pwd then I get the correct output e.g.

```
subprocess.call(["ls"]) # give me the list of all files
subprocess.call(["pwd"]) # gives me the location of current directory.
```

But when I run subprocess.call(["./test1.csh"]), I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/nishant/workspace/codec_implement/src/NTTool/raw2waveconvert.py", line 8, in <module>
    subprocess.call(["./test1.csh"])
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 524, in call
return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1308, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Where am I going wrong? Please suggest

Comment: Did you set the executable bit for the script? `chmod +x test1.csh`? And does it have a proper [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) as the first line?

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, it is running in the terminal i.e. c shell terminal and also the file is executable.

Comment: @nprak: `subprocess.call()` does *not* run any shell by default. Do you see `#!/bin/sh` at the top of `test1.csh`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the file `test1.csh` is executable. As Lukas Graf commented, also check the shebang (`#!...`) in the first line.

To confirm that, before run it through Python, run it in the shell.

```
$ ls -l test1.csh
...
$ ./test1.csh
```

The current working directory will be different from when you run it in the terminal. Specify the full path of the shell script. Or change the working directory configuration in the PyDev.

**UPDATE**

Prepend the shell executable:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["csh", "./test1.csh"])
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, it is running in the terminal i.e. c shell terminal and also the file is executable.

Comment: @user2658684, What happen if you specify the full path?

Comment: @falsetrue, Even If I specify the full path, It gives the same error and just to mention that the shell script is running in the c shell terminal.

Comment: @user2658684, How about `subprocess.call(["csh", "./test1.csh"])` ?

Comment: @falsetrue Thank you so much, It worked.. Thanks a lot. How can I upvote your answer as it helped me.